# Solving the Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to find transformation $F(s)$ for:
$f(t)=tsin(ωt)$

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems):

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\text{y}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{ds}}\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[\text{y}\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\right)\tag1$$

Now, [use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms):

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\sin\left(\omega x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\tag2$$

So, you will get:

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\sin\left(\omega x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{s}}\left(\frac{\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\right)\tag3$$

Comment: Thank you, but it is still complex to me. Are you able to show me step by step how to solve this? I think the biggest problem I have is to use the property because i get a different result

Comment: @DominikMazur show us what you've tried

Comment: I have no idea how to add equation here

Comment: @DominikMazur exactly as you did in your question.

Comment: So I make it alternate form: f(t) = 1/2 ite (escalating -itw) - 1/2 (esclating itw)

Comment: Then i tried to derivative: a/at(tsin(tω)) = sin (tω)+tωcos(tω

Comment: I tried to do it in different ways but i don't even understand what i do. I need someone who will explain it to me step by step how to do this transformation beacuse at the end i have always different results than my colleagues

Comment: @DominikMazur If you don't want to use the properties, try it find: $$\int_0^\infty t\sin(\omega t)\exp(-\text{s}t)\space\text{d}t$$

Comment: ok, but how? I don't understand this at all

Comment: @DominikMazur What is your background in calculus? Because if you have talked about Laplace transform your calculus class has to be taught beforehand.